# how to play dailymotion video in AVPlayer

Tags: ios, objective-c, avplayer, dailymotion-api

how can i play dailymotion video in `AVPlayer`.Is there any way to play URL link from dailymotin in iPhone.
i am trying this code for play video from URL.

```
videoPlay = [AVPlayer playerWithURL:@"Dailymotion URL"];
avPlayerLayer =[AVPlayerLayer playerLayerWithPlayer:videoPlay];
[avPlayerLayer setFrame:CGRectMake(0.0,0.0,playView.frame.size.width,playView.frame.size.height)];
[playView.layer addSublayer:avPlayerLayer];
[avPlayerLayer setBackgroundColor:[[UIColor greenColor]CGColor]];
[videoPlay seekToTime:kCMTimeZero];
[videoPlay play];
```

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Take a look at http://stackoverflow.com/questions/22149931/avplayer-doesnt-show-anything

Comment: @spassas thanks for your ans but it's not working for me.

Answer (score 0):

It is not possible to play Dailymotion video in AVPlayer, I rather suggest you to use the objective-c SDK to play dailymotion videos from iphone, which uses the Dailymotion player. You can get it at: https://github.com/dailymotion/dailymotion-sdk-objc

Comment: i have solve this issue.it's possible to play dailymotion video in avplayer.

Comment: just check my answer.

Answer (score 0):

```
NSString *urlString = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"http://www.dailymotion.com/embed/video/%@", videoId];
    NSURL *URL = [NSURL URLWithString:urlString];
    NSURLRequest *request = [NSURLRequest requestWithURL:URL];
    NSOperationQueue *queue = [[NSOperationQueue alloc] init];

    [NSURLConnection sendAsynchronousRequest:request
                                       queue:queue
                           completionHandler:^(NSURLResponse *response, NSData *data, NSError *connectionError) {

                               NSString *html = [[NSString alloc] initWithData:data encoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding];
                               NSString *str;
                               NSRange startRange = [html rangeOfString:@"var info = {"];
                               str = [html substringFromIndex:startRange.location];
                               NSRange endRange = [str rangeOfString:@"{"];
                               str = [str substringFromIndex:endRange.location];
                               endRange = [str rangeOfString:@"},"];
                               NSString *jsonString = [str substringToIndex:endRange.location+1];
                               jsonString = [jsonString stringByAppendingString:@"}"];
                               NSError *err = nil;
                               NSDictionary *result = [NSJSONSerialization JSONObjectWithData:[jsonString dataUsingEncoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding] options:0 error:&err];

                               if(err)
                               {
                                   NSLog(@"Error Parsing : %@",[err localizedDescription]);
                               }
```

Comment: Where on earth are you using avplayer in your code?