# AVPlayer layer not showing video content sometimes

Tags: ios, swift, avplayer, avplayerlayer

AVPlayer layer not showing video content sometimes but plays audio.
This happens some times not each time 
Here is my lines of code :

```
 override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()
        self.tempVideoPath = NSURL(fileURLWithPath: NSTemporaryDirectory()).appendingPathComponent("tmpMov.mov")
        self.player = AVPlayer(url: self.tempVideoPath!)
}

 override func viewDidAppear(_ animated: Bool) {
     super.viewDidAppear(animated)
     self.playerLayer = AVPlayerLayer(player: self.player)
     self.playerLayer?.frame = self.videoPlayer.bounds
     self.playerLayer?.backgroundColor = UIColor.yellow.cgColor
     self.videoPlayer.layer.addSublayer(playerLayer!)
     print("player = \(playerLayer?.bounds)")

 }
```

Help me to solve this issue.

Comment: `self.player` is not initialized. Or it is at some other place?

Comment: @PrafulD it is intialized

Comment: check this ... may be helpful to you http://stackoverflow.com/questions/22149931/avplayer-doesnt-show-anything

Comment: @PayalManiyar, If the suggestion from El Captain won't work. Can you post more of your code?

Comment: What is your URL ? Please post some more code related to initialisation.

Comment: @Wolverine  check my updated question

Comment: @PrafulD check my updated question

Comment: I am using Xcode 8.0 version. Will it be bug of Xcode 8.0?

Comment: if `self.tempVideoPath` is nil. Then also you will not able to the video.
check with this path 'http://rmcdn.2mdn.net/Demo/html5/output.mp4'

Comment: check self.tempVideoPath and self.player are not nil. Also check your.mov file is proper.

Comment: It plays audio of video so it is not possible that file is not at given path.

Comment: any other solution is there? @PrafulD,@Wolverine,@EI Captain v2.0

Comment: @PayalManiyar have you found solution? I'm having the same issue.

Answer (score 2):

the problem with you code is that the bounds of videoPlayer can change. 
So you need to add the following code to your view controller to change AVPlayerLayer's frame accordingly:

```
override func viewDidLayoutSubviews() {
    super.viewDidLayoutSubviews()

    playerLayer?.frame = view.bounds
}
```

Hope it helps.

Comment: Thanks this was the missing piece I was looking for. If the audio for your video is playing but the video is not showing this helps.